# comparison of an unsigned variable to 0

Tags: c, comparison, loops, data-types

When I execute the following loop :

```
 unsigned m;
 for( m = 10; m >= 0; --m ){
        printf("%d\n",m);
    }
```

the loop doesn't stop at m==0, it keeps executing interminably, so I thought that reason was that an unsigned cannot be compared to 0. But when I did the following test

```
unsigned m=9;
if(m >= 0)
    printf("m is positive\n");
else
    printf("m is negative\n");
```

I got this result:

```
m is positive
```

which means that the unsigned variable m was successfully compared to 0.
Why doesn't the comparison of m to 0 work in the for loop and works fine elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compile with all warnings enabled.

A test like `m >= 0` is **always *true*** if `m` is `unsigned`; so

```
if(m >= 0)
  printf("m is positive\n");
else
  printf("m is negative\n");
```

can be optimized as

```
printf("m is positive\n");
```

A recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), invoked as `gcc -Wall`  (or `gcc -Wall -O1`) would have warned you.

And a test like `m >0`  is the same as `m != 0`  (or just `m`)

And your `for ( m = 10; m >= 0; --m )` loop is understood as `for(m=10; TRUE; --m)` so loops indefinitely. Mabye you wanted `for (m=10; (int)m>=0; m--)` , then the test would fail when `m` becomes large enough to not fit in an `int` (without overflow to negative `int`). But such a `(int)m>=0` is ugly and unreadable, so avoid it.

Comment: But what's the advantage of using unsigned variables instead of signed ones?

Comment: A good answer for my question would be this post : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225949/using-unsigned-integers-in-c-c